# выбор категории slick-slider

Tags: html, css, jquery, slick.js

Есть sclick-slider
наверху кнопки:
Все категории: Футбол, Волейбол, Хоккей.
по умолчанию стоит все категории, как сделать чтобы при клике на футбол показывались картинки только с футболом, а остальные исчезали ?

Comment: Спасибо, Но мне нужно чтобы при клике на категорию слайдер сам менял на картинки с футболом, 
 или хоккеем или волейболом.

Comment: в смысле в одном слайдере но в разных категориях ?

Comment: Да, именно так !

Comment: ого ...тогда это типа window.location.hash типа этого ...я не знаю как такое делать ..извени за офтоп

Comment: может быть завести какой то data-attribute и по нему уже ориентировать какие картинки, а данные брать с body хм...

Comment: а сайт ваще на какой cms ?

Comment: Пока просто верстка, планирую на WP натянуть

Comment: так логически подумать можно вкрутить это но вот после того как посадишь на wp это скорее всего перестанет работать - так что лучше более компетентных людей подождать